# How to make web pages & put them in a Windows store C# app

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store

Basically I want to display some `html/js` content in a `WebView` browser within my Windows Store C# app. I have been trying unsuccessfully to do this - I can get the local web page to display in a `WebView` - but that's it.

How do you do the following:

1. Reference `JS` and `CSS` files within the `html` file loaded into the `WebView` - can relative urls be used in the `html` file to the `JS` and `CSS` ones (e.g. `scripts/eg.js`) or does `ms-appx-web:///` have to be used (e.g. `ms-appx-web:///ScriptrHTML/scripts/eg.js`)?
2. What's the best way to include `html`, `JS` and `CSS` resources into your project and guarantee they will be exported alongside the final app?

I couldn't find any tutorials on this, if you can I would love to see it!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you had a look at [How to load file resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781229.aspx)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes relative references will work
2. Make sure the Build Action for the various files is set to Content (just like the logos)